# I cannot get the data from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_canada = pd.read_excel(
    "./Canada.xlsx",
    sheet_name = "Canada by Citizenship",
    skiprows= range(20),
    skipfooter=2)

years = list(map(str, range(1980, 2014)))
serie = df_canada.loc['Haiti', years].plot(kind='line')
```

> But I get the following error:
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()
>
> KeyError: 'Haiti'

In order to solve this problem I put the code of the following way:

```
...
years = list(map(str, range(1980, 2014)))
df_canada.set_index('Country', inplace=True)
serie = df_canada.loc['Haiti', years].plot(kind='line')
...
```

But now I get the following error:

> KeyError: "None of [Index(['1980', '1981', '1982', '1983', '1984',
>   '1985', '1986', '1987', '1988',\n       '1989', '1990', '1991',
>   '1992', '1993', '1994', '1995', '1996', '1997',\n       '1998',
>   '1999', '2000', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006',\n
>   '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013'],\n
>   dtype='object')] are in the [index]"

Canda.columns:

> Index([    'Type', 'Coverage',     'AREA', 'AreaName', 
>   'REG',  'RegName',
>               'DEV',  'DevName',       1980,       1981,       1982,       1983,
>                1984,       1985,       1986,       1987,       1988,       1989,
>                1990,       1991,       1992,       1993,       1994,       1995,
>                1996,       1997,       1998,       1999,       2000,       2001,
>                2002,       2003,       2004,       2005,       2006,       2007,
>                2008,       2009,       2010,       2011,       2012,       2013],
>         dtype='object')

And of course this index exist in the xlsx file.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: could you provide/post the output of `print(df_canada.columns)`

Comment: In `Canda.columns` all the years are `int`s, but for some reason you are mapping your to strings. Instead of `years = list(map(str, range(1980, 2014)))` try `years = list(range(1980, 2014))` or you can map all the column names to strings: `Canda.columns = [str(column) for column in Canda.columns]` (but not both, obviously)

Comment: After you set_index as in your code, try this: `df_canada.loc['Haiti', list(range(1980, 2014))].plot(kind='line')`. Or you may slice directly from 1980:2013 as this: `df_canada.loc['Haiti', 1980:2013].plot(kind='line')`

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

df_canada = pd.read_excel('Canada.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Canada by Citizenship (2)') 


df_canada.set_index('OdName', inplace = True)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Change years to be integers instead of strings
years = list(range(1980, 2014)) 

# Simply sum across the years using our list of years instead of manually typing each year
df_canada['Total'] = df_canada[years].sum(axis=1) 


df_canada.loc['Haiti', years].plot(kind = 'line')

plt.title('Immigration from Albania')
plt.ylabel('Number of Immigrants')
plt.xlabel('years')``

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

it works..

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd  # For reading the data

# Read the dataset skipping top 20 rows(irrelevant) and second last row
df_canada = pd.read_excel("./canada.xlsx", skiprows=range(20), skipfooter=2)
#print(df_canada.head().to_string())  # View top 5 rows
df_canada.set_index('OdName', inplace = True)

# Change years to be integers instead of strings
years = list(range(1980, 2014))

# Simply sum across the years using our list of years instead of manually typing each year
df_canada['Total'] = df_canada[years].sum(axis=1)

df_canada.loc['Haiti', years].plot(kind='line')

plt.title("immigration from Haiti")
plt.ylabel('Number of immigrants')
plt.xlabel('Years')

plt.show()
```